# What does preventing path payments from taking offers from the source account protect against?

Tags: path-payment

I'm confused why Stellar path payments need to guard against offers from the source account being taken in a path. A case that this would prevent might be:

1. Account A - Offers 120 JPY for 1 USD. This is the best offer for JPY to USD. Currently holding 1 USD and 120 JPY.
2. Account A makes a path payment to Account B - Account B should receive 120 JPY, and Account A is sending USD.

This would fail, because Account A would need to take its own offer in order to fulfil this payment transaction.

I don't see why this needs to fail. I understand that Account A could just send 120 JPY directly, but then Account A would need to calculate exchange rates against all my up to date offers manually if my requirement was to find out how much this payment was supposed to cost in USD.